# yii2 file upload error- Call to a member function saveAs() on null

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've learned a little bit about yii2 framework, but I've got an error which I can't solve. I'm trying to add a image to signup form.

view:

```
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup', 'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
        
            <?= $form->field($model, 'voornaam')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'bedrijf') ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'telefoon') ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'username')?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
            </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

controller

```
public function actionSignup()
{
    $model = new SignupForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($user = $model->signup()) {
            if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

model:

```
public function signup()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return null;
    }
    
    $user = new User();
    
            $imageName = $user->username;
            $user->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($user,'file');
            $user->file->saveAs( 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension );
            $user->picture =  'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension; 
            
    $user->voornaam = $this->voornaam;
    $user->bedrijf = $this->bedrijf;
    $user->telefoon = $this->telefoon;
    $user->username = $this->username;
    $user->email = $this->email;
    $user->setPassword($this->password);
    $user->generateAuthKey();
    
    return $user->save() ? $user : null;
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Call to a member function saveAs() on null

What did I do wrong?
(I'm using the advanced template).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `$this` instead of `$user` or you should add

```
$user=$this
```

because simply $user is new instance and it's field are empty !

Comment: Thanks, this worked!

But it gives an next error:

Calling unknown method: yii\web\UploadedFile::save()

I'm using the vendor extension from yii itself

use yii\web\UploadedFile;

My save line:

$this->file->save();

Comment: i think you should use saveAs();

Comment: I managed to get it working,

What i did was, the last line from $this to $user, at the end it save the register for user.

$user->picture =  'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$this->file->extension;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mentioning wrong file path, you must mention rootpath for save function
for example

```
   $user->file->saveAs(\Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension );
```

Comment: i replaced the line with yours, and made an uploads folder in the root, but still didnt work and same error..

Answer (score 0):

I used separate upload function to upload a file and it's worked.

my view

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup','options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

            <?= $form->field($model, "files")->fileInput() ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
            </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

controller

```
public function actionSignup() {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->files = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'files');

            if ($model->upload() && $user = $model->signup()) {
                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                    return $this->goHome();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('signup', [
                    'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

and my model is

```
//declare variable
public $files; 

//add this to your rules
[['files'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg']


//File upload function
public function upload()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->files->saveAs('../web/uploads/' . $this->files->baseName. '.' .$this->files->extension);
            $this->picture = '../web/uploads/' . $this->files->baseName. '.' .$this->files->extension;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false; 
        }
    }


    public function signup()
    {
            $user = new User();
            $user->username = $this->username;
            $user->email = $this->email;  
            $user->picture = $this->picture;
            $user->setPassword($this->password);
            $user->generateAuthKey();
            if ($user->save()) {
                return $user;
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing you my solution, change the path to uploads folder to `../uploads/`

In your model try changing `saveAs` function as shown below

```
$user->file->saveAs( '../uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension );
```

I am a beginner in yii2, I faced a problem when i tried the file upload code from
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload,

this solved my problem